# How to fetch the timestamp value from postgres as it it?

Tags: postgresql

In my postgres db, i'm having UTC timestamp value. Ex,  "2021-09-11 23:05:26" when i try to quesry the particular value from dBeaver client, it prints the same it is. The query is,

```
SELECT * from glacier_restore_progress where id=1;
```

But when I try to get the same value from an API by querying the same query, i get different value like this, "2021-09-11T23:05:26.000Z". My contry's timezone is GMT+5:30.
This is the query function,

```
const getQuery = (id) => `SELECT time_stamp from glacier_restore_progress where id=1`
```

Comment: You need to fix your "API" code. This is not a Postgres problem.